# Firewall rule for using google cloud sdk from virtual machine

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, firewall

I'm using Google Cloud SDK (dot net) to read data from cloud datastore. I'm deploying it on internal virtual machine and need to setup firewall rules to allow access to specific IP/Ports for Google Cloud Datastore SDK. Where do I find the IP/Port details for the firewall setup?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Private Access Options for Services](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options) to see which option works for you.